# Is there a way to perform Add Edit Delete Read for FullCalendar?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, fullcalendar, crud

How to do a FullCalendar with all crud functions in MVC without using json if possible? Just using raw sql.

My current fullcalendar code can only display the current date only. What must I do to in Controller and View to allow sql crud?

Thanks!

Comment: write some code to allow inserting, updating and deleting of data. There's no feature in fullCalendar for this directly, since in the end it's up to you how you save your changes, but you can hook into fullCalendar's callbacks such as `select`, `eventClick`, `eventDrop` etc to give you a way to detect when the user wants to make a new event, or select an existing one for changes. After that you're on your own. Probably the best way is to use some AJAX calls so you don't have to keep reloading the page. There's quite a lot to do, to address all this functionality is too much for an SO question.

Comment: P.S. If you search you might even find some examples or plugins which help with the integration of fullCalendar and MVC. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MVC+fullcalendar+CRUD+example&oq=MVC+fullcalendar+CRUD+example&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.3815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8